# Convert List to String and back to List Python 3

Tags: python

If I type:

```
>>> list(str([0, 0, 0]))
```

I get:
    `['[', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '0', ']']`

How would I make it so that I get `[0, 0, 0]` instead?

Comment: Why list > string > list? What's the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension like this:

```
my_str = str([0, 0, 0])
my_list = [int(s) for s in my_str.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(',')]
```

Now you have:

```
>>> my_str
'[0, 0, 0]'
>>> my_list
[0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is cast every item into a string. Do this:

```
>>> orig_list = [0, 0, 0]
>>> new_list = [str(item) for item in orig_list]

>>> new_list
['0', '0', '0']
```

Comment: Output should be `[0, 0, 0]`. Not `['0', '0', '0']`

Comment: I wrote 'if' that's what the OP wants to achieve. It seemed like a slightly nonsensical question

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to use in a production code but you can use

```
eval("".join(list(str([0, 0, 0]))))
```